# Will this series converge? If so, what is its limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, faq

If $a_n=(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})/2$ and $a_1, a_2$ are given, will this series converge? And if so, what is the limit?

By intuition I think it converges to $(a_1+2a_2)/3$ , but I am not able to prove it.

Comment: Try to determine the $n$th term in the sequence in terms of $n$, $a_1$ and $a_2$. You should notice that $a_n=f(n)a_1+g(n)a_2$, where $f,g$ are some functions related to $2^n$ (and you can prove this by induction). Try to prove that $f(n)\to\frac{1}{3}$ and $g(n)\to\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Please use the word sequence instead of series. They have different meanings in maths.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$2a_n-a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}=0$$

Using Recurrence Relation [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) , $$a_n=A+B\left(-\frac12\right)^n$$